# TAR operation not working with variable in filename

Tags: shell, sh, tar

```
# Current date
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M`

# Compress folder
tar czf "$now.tar.gz" dump/
```

does not work. No tar is created. But

```
tar czf someName.tar.gz dump/
```

works fine. Can someone point out the problem? It seems that

```
tar czf "$now.tar.gz" dump/
```

is not accepted as filename. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `--force-local` flag help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:

> If the archive file name includes a colon (‘:’), then it is assumed to
>   be a file on another machine[...]

which lays here

```
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M`
```

I replaced the : with - and it works fine. More info here: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_46.html#file